# Spam Filter and SPF rejection

Tags: smtp, spam, relay, postfix-mta

Spam Filters such as TitanSpam or Everycloud are become more and more popular. However using those services with hosted e-Mail is often not possible since the Spam Filter which acts as a Relay changes the IP of the sender. When then the receiving e-Mail server checks SPF records the IP does no longer match and the mail is rejected. Hosted e-Mail providers do not allow disabling SPF checking. Is there any other solution to still use Spam Filters with hosted e-Mail?

Answer (score 0):

A good solution for this problem is using DKIM with DMARC. DKIM signs the mail, DMARC set the handling reject or quarantine on the receiving server.

Use a DKIM key with more or equal 1024 bits, lower are expired.